# Can't run mysql from terminal

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I have installed mysql and it works well with RazorSQL.
But for some reason I need to run it from terminal, I type:

```
mysql -u root
```

From terminal, but it says: command not found.
It's started and working with RazorSQL, why doesn't it work from terminal?

Comment: Where is MySQL installed?  A default OSX install may not go into the $PATH.  For example, check in /usr/local/mysql/bin.  You may need to either add that to your $PATH or launch with the full path `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p`

Comment: Fits better at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have to update `/etc/paths` to include the location of the MySQL binaries. For me on OS X Lion, that meant adding `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.